# Conversion of char array to integer using atoi caused segmentation fault

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to convert a char array to an integer using `atoi`. But the code below produces a segmentation fault.

**CODE:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main(){
    char a[10] = "1234567890";
    int x,i;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){
        x=atoi(a[i]);
        printf("%d",x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What have I done wrong and is ther anything I can use instead of using `atoi`?

Comment: There are two common problems in C -- Variable initialization, memory allocation and off-by-one errors. You need to allocate one more byte for `\0` character which terminates a string.

Comment: strlen() is expecting the string to be terminated.

Comment: You also need to read some documentation for the functions you try to use. `atoi()` takes a pointer, your compiler should be complaining about this.

Comment: What would be the expected output of this program ? Maybe you want just `x = atoi(a);` whithout the for loop.

Comment: In addition to the point made by @Blastfurnace, any recently modern compiler will complain about the initialization of 'a', with an error of 'array bounds overflow'.  Even with a low warning level setting. (I just tried it on VS2013 with a warning level of 2 and I get that error, not warning).

Comment: @Michael the expected output for this code is only 1234567890. But thanks David and you cleared the doubt.

Comment: Read the compiler output, there should be an error about `atoi(a[i])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
char a[10] = "1234567890";
```

This leaves no room for the null terminator. And so `strlen(a)` results in undefined behaviour. Declare `a` like this:

```
const char a[] = "1234567890";
```

or like this:

```
const char *a = "1234567890";
```

Subsequently, your call to `atoi` is incorrect. You are meant to pass a pointer to a null terminated string. You pass a `char`. Perhaps you mean to pass `a+i`:

```
x=atoi(a+i);
```

Then again, it's not at all obvious why you are looping. What's wrong with:

```
x = atoi(a);
```

Also, `atoi` is a notoriously gnarly function to use. It doesn't give you any meaningful way to detect errors in your input. A better approach would be to use `sscanf`.

You might put this all together like so:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char *a = "1234567890";
    for(size_t i = 0; a[i]; i++)
    {
        int x;
        if (sscanf(a + i, "%d", &x) == 1)
        {
            printf("%d\n", x);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that is:

```
1234567890
234567890
34567890
4567890
567890
67890
7890
890
90
0
```

But I doubt that's what you want. I suspect that you really want this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x;
    if (sscanf("1234567890", "%d", &x) == 1)
    {
        printf("%d\n", x);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
1234567890
```

Comment: @David still getting the same seg fault

Comment: @David  Warning message when compling atoi.c: In function 'main':
atoi.c:8:3: warning: passing argument 1 of 'atoi' makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
In file included from atoi.c:2:0:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:147:12: note: expected 'const char *' but argument is of type 'char'

Comment: my expected answer is 1234567890.so, that why i used loop to convert byte by byte.